# How to select value?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to choose (click) the size for ring size in the ring_size list. there are two loop 1st working to pick the value from ring_size and another picking the seperate values.

I want to choose or click on the appropriate size in 2nd loop. Image attached of elements.

Output I need is when I run code choose / click / select size 4, 5, 6 & another loop 6.25, 6.5, 7.5 and so on..

image attached.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSjEo.jpg)

Code

```
ring_sizes = ['4, 5, 6','6.25, 6.5, 7.5','9, 10, 11','8.25, 8.75, 3.5']

for i in ring_sizes:
    size_string = i
    size_list = size_string.split(', ')    

    for size in size_list:
        options = driver.find_element_by_tag_name(size)
        
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.get('www.example.com')

driver.quit()
```

Comment: The screenshot of the page is very helpful but a screenshot of HTML is not. Please copy the relevant HTML and post it in your question, properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

```
for size in size_list:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='msku-variation-values-3']/ul/li[.={}]".format(size))).click()
```

Might want to fix your array first it has ' and , in it but to click the option related to that value you click the li with that text.

Comment: This is the way I would have done it (cleaning up the original list and getting rid of the single quotes etc...) the problem is the OP wants to loop through these in sets `4,5,6` then another loop for `6.25,6.5,7.5` etc, not one size at a time.  I don't understand that requirement myself and your solution seems more simple.

Comment: Changed it to the fix.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained WHY you need to do this in nested loops so it's hard to know how to handle that. On the surface, your code doesn't demonstrate the need to do it in separate loops.

Rather than storing them as an array of strings and then splitting the string, it's easier just to do nested arrays. I've renamed your variables to something more related to what they hold. The code below will click them in order, inside of the inner loop, but since we don't know if/what you want to do between the loops, I've left a comment placeholder. You were also switching to default content but you never switched into something other than default content, so I removed that. I also removed the sleep and the navigation to a URL because they didn't seem to do anything related to your scenario.

```
ring_groups = [[4, 5, 6],[6.25, 6.5, 7.5],[9, 10, 11],[8.25, 8.75, 3.5]]
for ring_group in ring_groups:
    for ring_size in ring_group:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='msku-variation-values-3']//li[text()='" + str(ring_size) + "']").click()
    # do something else?
driver.quit()
```